# How does the 'case' statement work with constants?

Tags: ruby, class, constants, switch-statement

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have the following method:

```
# Note: The 'class_name' parameter is a constant; that is, it is a model class name.
def my_method(class_name)
  case class_name
  when Article then make_a_thing
  when Comment then make_another_thing
  when ...     then ...     
  else raise("Wrong #{class_name}!")
  end  
end
```

I would like to understand why, in the `case` statement above, it always runs the `else` "part" when I execute method calls like `my_method(Article)`, `my_method(Comment)` and so on.

How can I solve the issue? Does someone have advice  how to handle this?

Comment: Would it be because `case` statement use the `===` and that a class cannot be subsumed to itself ?

Comment: How to you invoke this method? That is, what arguments are you passing to it? This makes all the difference.

Comment: @Alex Wayne - I am passing constant names (model class names). As wrote in the question, I run methods as `my_method(Article)`, `my_method(Comment)` and so on.

Comment: @user12882 you should rename your `class_name` variable to `klass` to avoid confusion. What you call a model class name is a name, hence a String. What you are actually passing is `Class`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `case` calls `===`, and [`===` on Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (or specifically Module, which Class descends from) is implemented like so:

> #### `mod === obj` → `true` or `false`
>
> Case Equality—Returns `true` if `obj` is an instance of `mod` or one of `mod`’s descendants. Of limited use for modules, but can be used in case statements to classify objects by class.

This means that for any constant except `Class` & `Module` (e.g. `Foo`), `Foo === Foo` always returns `false`. As a result, you always get the `else` condition in your `case` statement.

Instead just call `case` with the object itself, instead of its class, or use `if` statements.

Comment: This is actually wrong. `Class === Class` is `true`. `Module === Module` is also `true`.

Comment: @sawa Indeed. Updated. Those are true because `Class` & `Module` are in fact both instances of `Class`, which descends from `Module`. (Isn't that so mind-bogglingly meta?)

Answer (score 4):

Pass an object reference to the method, as in the background it uses the === operator, so these will fail. e.g.

```
obj = 'hello'
case obj.class
when String
  print('It is a string')
when Fixnum
  print('It is a number')
else
  print('It is not a string')
end
```

This on the other hand, works fine:

```
obj = 'hello'
case obj  # was case obj.class
when String
  print('It is a string')
when Fixnum
  print('It is a number')
else
  print('It is not a string')
end
```

See a relevant answer to "How to write a switch statement in Ruby" https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694333/1092644

Answer (score 2):

You can add `to_s` to the class constant if you just want to compare the equality of names.

```
def my_method(class_name)
  case class_name.to_s
  when 'Article'
    make_a_thing
  when 'Comment'
    make_another_thing

  ... ...

  end  
end
```