# Case statement in Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, slim-lang

Is there a way to write a case statement in Slim for the following example. I made some changes for the StackOverflow question: [How to write a switch statement in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-to-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby)

```
case a
when 1..5
  = "It's between 1 and 5"
when 6
  = "It's 6"
when String
  = "You passed a string"
else
  = "You gave me #{a} -- I have no idea what to do with that."
end
```

I tried the following but generates an error.

```
= case @taxon.name
  = when "Wedding Cakes"
    div.taxon-descripiton Wedding Cake Description
```

This is what I am told

```
... syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_when
; @output_buffer.safe_concat(("<when>\"Weddin...
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`=` is used when you want to render something, when you want to call some ruby logic without rendering anything in a view you should use `-`:

```
- case @taxon.name    
- when "Wedding Cakes"    
  div.taxon-descripiton Wedding Cake Description
```

I am not sure this will solve your problem though, have you considered moving this logic to a decorator anyway?

Comment: I am not sure what a decorator is, neither did I find any Slim Decorator in the web, could you give me a hint. I just am curious to know. I will try it and if it works accept as an answer. Thanks for the great help!

Comment: Great it worked! But would you be kind enough to tell me what `decorator` is?

Comment: A decorator is just another way to extract logic from the views to keep them clean, if you want to get started with them I suggest you take a look at the draper gem https://github.com/drapergem/draper. There is a railcast somewhere to learn the basics as well. :)