# Can procs be used with case statements in Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, ruby-2.0

I remember something about procs being allowed in `case` statements in Ruby 2.0, but I can't google it.

I tried checking [Ruby 2.0.0 NEWS](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/NEWS) and [How to write a switch statement in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby). I also visited http://ruby-doc.org , but the link it had for keywords was for Ruby 1.9, not Ruby 2.0.

Are procs allowed in case statements?

Comment: I thought it was from before.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes.

```
2.0.0p0 :001> lamb = ->(x){ x%2==1 }
#=> #<Proc:0x007fdd6a97dd90@(irb):1 (lambda)> 

2.0.0p0 :002> case 3; when lamb then p(:yay); end
:yay
#=> :yay 

2.0.0p0 :003> lamb === 3
#=> true 

2.0.0p0 :007> lamb === 2
#=> false
```

However, this is no different than 1.9.1 since [`Proc#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) was defined back then. Since ruby-docs seems to have a problem showing this method, to be clear the documentation says that `proc === obj`:

> Invokes the block with `obj` as the proc's parameter like `#call`. It is to allow a proc object to be a target of `when` clause in a `case` statement.

---

For the Ruby beginner, then `when` clause in Ruby's `case` statements takes the value in the clause and calls the `===` method on it, passing in the argument to the case statement. So, for example, this code…

```
case "cats"
  when /^cat/ then puts("line starts with cat!")
  when /^dog/ then puts("line starts with dog!")
end
```

…runs `/^cat/ === "cats"` to decide if it's a match; the `RegExp` class defines the `===` method to perform regex matching. Thus, you can use your own object in a `when` clause as long as you define `===` for it.

```
Moddable = Struct.new(:n) do
  def ===(numeric)
    numeric % n == 0
  end
end

mod4 = Moddable.new(4)
mod3 = Moddable.new(3)

12.times do |i|
  case i
    when mod4
      puts "#{i} is a multiple of 4!"
    when mod3
      puts "#{i} is a multiple of 3!"
  end
end

#=> 0 is a multiple of 4!
#=> 3 is a multiple of 3!
#=> 4 is a multiple of 4!
#=> 6 is a multiple of 3!
#=> 8 is a multiple of 4!
#=> 9 is a multiple of 3!
```

Comment: `l` looks awfully similar to `1` on Stack Overflow. I was wondering for a minute if George Orwell had been put in charge of the math department! (PS: is there any documentation on using procs in a case statement?)

Comment: I linked to the 1.9.1 docs, but it seems that all modern versions of the docs fail to provide a proper header for the method, making it very confusing. I'll edit the question with the documentation on `Proc#===`.

Comment: Thanks, phroggie, for refreshing that `Proc#===` for me.