# Correct way to use Ruby's case statement with 'and' keyword

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

What is the correct way to use the 'and' keyword within the case statement in ruby?
Here is an example:

Write a program that asks the user for age and prints the following string based on input:

```
0 to 2      =>     "baby"
3 to 6      =>     "little child"
7 to 12     =>     "child"
13 to 18    =>     "youth"
18+         =>     "adult"
```

Example 1

```
INPUT
Enter the age:
3
OUTPUT
little child*
```

---

```
puts "Enter the age:" 
age = gets.chomp.to_i
#Write your code here 
case (age)
    when age >= 0 and <= 2      then puts("baby")
    when age > 2 and < 7        then puts("little child")
    when age > 6 and < 13       then puts("child")
    when age > 12 and < 18      then puts("youth")
    when age > 18               then puts("adult")
end
```

#

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?"

Comment: when (age >= 0 and age <= 2) then puts "baby" etc. But then you don't even need "case (age)", you can simply write "case". Besides, I think this question is more suitable for SO than Programmers.

Comment: I'm guessing my syntax is incorrect because the interpreter is displaying this -  syntax error, unexpected keyword_and, expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'

Answer (score 0):

1) <, <= etc needs 'objects' like numbers or strings on both sides.
2) With help from Chuck's answer from [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby) (age>=0 and age<=2) will evaluate to `true` THEN this `true` will be compared to age: `age === true` which gives you false.
You can use `ranges` in your case statement:

`case age

  when 0..2 then puts 'baby' #with 2 dots, it will check 0, 1, 2

  when 3...7 then puts 'little child' #with 3 dots, it will check 3, 4, 5, 6[no 7!]

  when 7...13 then puts 'child'

  when 13...18 then puts 'youth'

  when 19..120 then puts 'adult'`