# Shortening an if-else structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have written something like this, the same if-else logic I knew from Visual Basic 6.0, but I am sure there is a better "Ruby way" of writing it.

Can you please show me how it would look like in Ruby world?

```
  if params[:medication_name].nil?
    med_name = 'all'
  elsif params[:medication_name] == 'undefined'
    med_name = 'all'
  else
    med_name = params[:medication_name]
  end
```

Comment: Not really a better "ruby way" but you could try a ternary statement.

Comment: you can use `defined?` at least for the 2nd branch

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/948135/128421.

Comment: Side note: it is a best-practice in Ruby to move your assignment to the result of the conditional. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bf0ba38c44968399766ada48076c9222

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case, something like this:

```
med_name = params[:medication_name] 
med_name = 'all' if [nil, 'undefined'].include? med_name
```

For more general long chains of `if`/`elsif`/`else`, look at [`case` statements](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/).  They're overkill in this case, but here's an example:

```
med_name = case params[:med_name]
   when 'undefined', nil 
     'all'
   else
      params[:med_name]
end
```

Answer (score 8):

There are several different ways you could simplify this, for example:

```
med_name = params[:medication_name]
med_name = 'all' if med_name.nil? or med_name == 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 2):

Unique to Ruby:

```
med_name = {nil=>'all', 'undefined'=>'all'}[params[:medication_name]] || params[:medication_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do as below :

```
val = [nil, 'undefined'].include?(params[:medication_name]) ? "all" : params[:medication_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `case` statements is a Ruby-friendly way. If you're checking against one value, you can do:

```
case params[:medication_name]
    when nil?
        med_name = 'all'
    when 'undefined'
        med_name = 'all'
    else
        med_name = params[:medication_name]
end
```

Another way is to test against multiple values:

```
foo = true
bar = false
case
    when foo == true
        puts "foo is true"
    when foo == false
        puts "foo is false"
    when bar == true
        puts "bar is true"
    when bar == false
        puts "bar is false"
    else
        puts "foo and bar are neither true or false!"
end
```