# Stuck on Learnstreet Ruby lesson 7.9 Introducing || Operator

Tags: ruby

Attempting to learn Ruby as my first programming language. I was understanding everything fine to this point, but I am drawing a blank at this exercise  and not sure where to even get started with this and could use some help.

9: Introducing || operator

Similar to the logical and operator &&, we have a logical or operator ||. The character | is located right above your enter key on the keyboard and is called a pipe. Similar to double ampersand, this one is also commonly referred to as double pipe. The || operator is used if any of the conditions can be true. For example - if number == 1 || number == 3 returns true if number is either 1 or 3. Simple right? Implement a method dinner_choice as per the instructions in the code editor.

This function should return:

1. "steak" if celebrity is "brad pitt" or "angelina jolie"
2. "italian" if celebrity is "ashton kutcher" or "demi moore"
3. "french" if celebrity is none of the above

This is my attempt.

```
def dinner_choice(celebrity)
return "steak" if celebrity == "brad pitt" || celebrity == "angelina jolie"
return "italian" if celebrity == "ashton kutcher" || celebrity == "demi moore"
else return "french"
end
```

end

Comment: what attempt have you made??

Comment: `||`is just another way of saying `or`.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, this is what you want

```
def dinner_choice(celebrity)
  return "steak" if celebrity == "brad pitt" || celebrity == "angelina jolie"
  return "italian" if celebrity == "ashton kutcher" || celebrity == "demi moore"
  return "french"
end
```

You don't want the last `else` at the end.  You can simply use `return "french"` because if any of the statements above it match, it won't get to that line.

Comment: Last else is syntax error, as there is no *normal* if statement, and else doesn't work with 'value if condition' version.

Answer (score 0):

The general form you're looking for is to write statements like this:

```
def dinner_choice celebrity
  return "steak" if celebrity == "Brad Pitt"
  return "foo" if # add programming here
end
```

You'll check the celebrity variable to see if it's something your method knows how to handle, and give the result that goes with the input.

The explicit `return` tells the Ruby interpreter to stop evaluating the rest of the code in the method and give the result specified.

You could also experiment with [case statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby), but IMO they're ugly and hard to maintain in most situations.

Comment: Thanks for the general form I was able to get it started from that