# Ruby trouble with breaking loop

Tags: ruby, loops, break

All right, I have the programming aptitude of a goldfish, so I could use some help. I have the following code (please excuse my terrible sense of humor):

```
puts 'Do you have a middle name?'
answer=gets.chomp.downcase
 while true 
 if answer != ('yes' || 'no')
  puts 'Yes or no answers only, dumbass.'
  puts 'So I\'ll ask again. Do you have a middle name?'
  answer=gets.chomp.downcase
elsif answer == ('yes' || 'no')
if answer == 'yes'
  puts 'Cool. What is it?'
  middlename=gets.chomp
  puts middlename +'? That\'s dumb.'
  break
if answer == 'no'
  puts 'I guess you aren\'t cool enough.'
  break
end
end
end
end
puts 'Well, smell ya later.'
```

It works mostly fine, but I have one problem: choosing the no option. I cannot figure out how to get that to work. It will loop fine, and choosing the yes option works.

Basically, my question is: how do I create a loop with two break options?

Comment: The loop that you posted above has two `break` options...

Comment: Just a heads-up: this may offend lexicographers who believe 'dumbass' should be hyphenated. `'I guess you aren\'t cool enough.'` is normally written `"I guess you ain't cool enough"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this you should use a `case/when` which is a Ruby `switch` statement because having all of those `if/end` blocks will get confusing fast.

**Also please read this guide:** https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide
It will teach you how to properly format your ruby code.

```
puts 'Do you have a middle name?'
answer=gets.chomp.downcase

case answer
when 'yes' 
  puts 'Cool. What is it?'
  middlename=gets.chomp
  puts middlename +'? That\'s dumb.'
when 'no'
  puts 'I guess you aren\'t cool enough.'
else  
  puts 'Yes or no answers only, dumbass.'
  puts 'So I\'ll ask again. Do you have a middle name?'
  answer=gets.chomp.downcase
end

puts 'Well, smell ya later.'
```

And if you always want it to `loop` when they don't answer `yes` or `no`. You can do that by wrapping the code block in a `loop` as follows:

```
puts 'Do you have a middle name?'
answer=gets.chomp.downcase

loop do
  case answer
  when 'yes' 
    puts 'Cool. What is it?'
    middlename=gets.chomp
    puts middlename +'? That\'s dumb.'
    break
  when 'no'
    puts 'I guess you aren\'t cool enough.'
    break
  else  
    puts 'Yes or no answers only, dumbass.'
    puts 'So I\'ll ask again. Do you have a middle name?'
    answer=gets.chomp.downcase
  end
end

puts 'Well, smell ya later.'
```

See this answer: [How to write a switch statement in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby)

Comment: This solution avoids the repetition of the literals _yes_ and _no_ in the code in question.  That's good.

Comment: Wayne, the loop structure you've used is often seen when the user typically performs several actions before selecting "quit".  Here you are using it just to get a valid answer.  It might be clearer to have something like `loop do; puts 'Do you have a middle name?'; break if['yes', 'no'].include(answer=gets.chomp.downcase); print "So I'll ask again "; end`, then `if answer == 'yes'...else...end`. (SO: I wish you'd allow better formatting in comments.)

Comment: @Cary, I'm not the author of the code you are commenting on.  However, I agree that it's usually better to ask the question separately from the code the acts upon the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`if answer != ('yes' || 'no')` isn't doing what you think it is.  Since `'yes'` is non-nil, which is true, the logical OR is short-circuited and the value of the parenthetic expression is always `'yes'`. Try `if answer != 'yes' && answer != 'no'` instead.

Comment: or unless['yes','no'].include?(answer)