# Ruby challenge: experienced developers opinions

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working on some ruby problems *geared towards new developers*, but I would like the opinions of experienced developers on this. Sorry for the long post, and I really appreciate your time and opinions.

**Problem Question**

> Write a function, `nearest_larger(arr, i)` which takes an array and an
>   index.  The function should return another index, `j`: this should
>   satisfy:
>
> - (a) `arr[i] < arr[j]`, AND
> - (b) there is no `j2` closer to `i` than `j` where `arr[i] < arr[j]`.
>
> In case of ties (see example below), choose the earliest (left-most)
>   of the two indices. If no number in `arr` is larger than `arr[i]`,
>   return `nil`.
>
> Difficulty: 2/5

**Rspec Test**

```
describe "#nearest_larger" do
  it "handles a simple case to the right" do
    nearest_larger([2,3,4,8], 2).should == 3
  end

  it "handles a simple case to the left" do
    nearest_larger([2,8,4,3], 2).should == 1
  end

  it "treats any two larger numbers like a tie" do
    nearest_larger([2,6,4,8], 2).should == 1
  end

  it "should choose the left case in a tie" do
    nearest_larger([2,6,4,6], 2).should == 1
  end

  it "handles a case with an answer > 1 distance to the left" do
    nearest_larger([8,2,4,3], 2).should == 0
  end

  it "handles a case with an answer > 1 distance to the right" do
    nearest_larger([2,4,3,8], 1).should == 3
  end

  it "should return nil if no larger number is found" do
    nearest_larger( [2, 6, 4, 8], 3).should == nil
  end
end
```

**Solution**

```
def nearest_larger arr, idx
diff = 1
  loop do
    l = idx - diff
    r = idx + diff
    return l    if (l >= 0) && (arr[l] > arr[idx])
    return r    if (r < arr.length) && (arr[r] > arr[idx])
    return nil  if (l < 0) && (r >= arr.length)
    diff += 1
  end
end
```

**Feedback**

1. How would you go about working towards a solution for this problem? (what's your process?)
2. In your opinion do find the **Problem Question** clear and easy to understand?
3. How long should it take you to solve this problem? (10min, 20min, ...?)
4. Do agree with the level of difficulty? (Keep in mind this is geared towards new developers)
5. If willing: please post your own solution, showcasing your style of solving this problem.

I decided to post this question because I know how easy it can be for new developer to get stuck on a problem and not know what to write first. I'm hoping your responses will give an insight on how you would work through a problem that you perceive as a challenge.

Comment: +1 just for such awesome presentation...

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thanks and I look forward to reading your response.

Comment: I am not the experienced guy, as you asked us. But I will become very soon! :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm sure that whatever you can share on your insights and process will be helpful to others and it is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I find the rspec a lot more descriptive than the problem statement. Nearer and closer aren't well defined and it's easy to crosslink them with the value rather than the index.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog I share your view on that as well. Please consider up voting the question to help get the attention of people capable of sharing deeper insights to the problem.

Comment: Usually, an off-topic question isn't all that good in the first place.  This question is _awesome_.  It also has some really good answers.  Despite it being technically off-topic for its breadth and call for opinion, I'm voting to leave it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you go about working towards a solution for this problem? (what's your process?)

Start with a simple example, e.g. one of the tests. It is discovered that if the array element `arr[i-1]` is greater than `arr[i]` then you can immediately return `i-1` as the answer. So you can just check in succession: `i-1, i+1, i-2, i+2, i-3, i+3` etc. and return the first index that satisfies the inequality.

> In your opinion do find the Problem Question clear and easy to understand?

Yes; the tests help but it only confirmed my understanding from the worded problem.

> How long should it take you to solve this problem? (10min, 20min, ...?)

For a student in a test/classroom environment, no more than 10min. Depending on how much preparatory material they have had before this, maybe even less.

> Do agree with the level of difficulty? (Keep in mind this is geared towards new developers)

Yes, 2/5 seems right.

> If willing: please post your own solution, showcasing your style of solving this problem.

```
def nearest_larger( a, i )
  2.upto([i,a.length-i].max << 1) do |k|
    j = (k&1).zero? ? i - (k>>1) : i + (k>>1)
    return j if 0 <= j && j < a.length && a[i] < a[j]
  end
  return nil
end
```

---

### Addendum: Thinking in Bits

This addendum will go through in greater detail the problem solving that went into the above solution for the benefit of new programmers.

As was mentioned in the answer to Question #1 above, the return value of `nearest_larger` is the first index `j` for which `a[i] < a[j]` as `j` iterates through the sequence

```
i-1, i+1, i-2, i+2, i-3, i+3, ...
```

This opens the way to a sub-problem, which is how to generate this sequence of numbers. When actually writing the program, I used comments as a "scratch pad", and in the code had something like this:

```
# -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, ...            (Sequence G)
```

from which the prior sequence is constructed by just adding `i` to each term. Call this Sequence G. Now this is where a "binary intuition" would come into play. Consider a simple sequence of binary numbers that increases by one after each term, shown in Column A, and the familiar decimal representation is shown in Column B:

```
   A   B     C   D   E   F
----------------------------
0000   0   000   0   0   0
0001   1   000   1   0   0
0010   2   001   0   1  -1
0011   3   001   1   1   1
0100   4   010   0   2  -2
0101   5   010   1   2   2
0110   6   011   0   3  -3
0111   7   011   1   3   3
```

Now split the bits in each number into two groups: all the bits other than bit 0 (the right-most bit) as shown in Column C, and bit 0 shown in Column D. In other words, concatenate C and D to get A. The decimal representation of C is in column E. Notice that column D conveniently flips between 0 and 1, just as in Sequence G the numbers flip between negative and positive. We will use this to construct column F, which is the same as E, except when D is 0 make F negative. Finally, if we just start in the above table at A=0010 (or B=2) then Column F gives us the above Sequence G.

So now how do we get Column F from A in code? This is where bit operations come in to play.

`C = A >> 1` - The `>>` [right-shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift) shifts the bits on the LHS (left-hand side) by RHS (right-hand side). In this case, each value A is shifted to the right one place. The right-most bit is lost. Mathematically, it is the same as dividing by 2 and dropping the remainder in this case (B/2 == E with remainder dropped.)

`D = A & 1` - The `&` is the [bitwise AND operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). By "anding" A with 1, we select only bit 0; see the link in the prior sentence for more detail. This gives us Column D.

Putting this together in the code, we'll have `k` be the iteration variable that starts at 2 and increments by 1 each time. Then the above analysis gives us `j`:

```
j = (k&1).zero? ? i - (k>>1) : i + (k>>1)
```

The first value for `j` which is both in bounds and for which `a[i] < a[j]` holds is automatically the answer, so it can be returned immediately:

```
return j if 0 <= j && j < a.length && a[i] < a[j]
```

Finally, if there are no valid values for `j` then return `nil`. Other than calculating a lower upper-bound for `k`, which is left as a homework problem, that is the entirety of the `nearest_larger` function.

In actual practice, for a problem like this, a readable solution as posed in the OP is preferable since it is more clear and accessible to a wider group of programmers. This present approach was motivated by an opportunity to demonstrate the use of bit operations.

Comment: +1 for such a clean answer and detailed process. I'm in awe of your solution too. Your code is quite different from mine, yet it passes all of the tests. I assume this took you less than 10 minutes to code and you didn't just refactor my solution to create yours? Please consider up voting the question as I would like to see how other developers would respond here as well. Again -- Great job! Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @feed_me_code Thanks - I actually had a bug that was just fixed (`k` wasn't going high enough for some cases not covered by the tests) so in that sense I had to take more than 10 minutes. No, I didn't look at your answer in detail until after, but if this were a school test I probably wouldn't have messed with the bits and just did something more straightforward like in your solution.

Comment: Right on, your solution is quite advanced. What is this called: `>>` and what is it doing exactly? Can you share a link to doc's on it. And what is `k&1` is that a `proc` on 1? You clearly have skills that I'm striving to acquire. Thanks again, Matt. By the way .. where did you learn this style of coding? I wouldn't call it Ruby like, more like C style in my opinion.

Comment: @feed_me_code It's all bitwise operations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation I'll be happy to add an addendum to the answer going into detail on this solution later today when I need to take another break from work. :) Where did I learn it? Every programmer should take a course on assembly language at some point. Here you get a feel for what is going on at the processor level. From that point, it is about flexing that muscle at every opportunity without p*ssing off your co-workers. :)

Comment: That sounds great Matt, thanks I look forward to reading your update later. Cheers!

Comment: @feed_me_code Updated. Btw feel free to unmark my answer if you want more answers; coders are more likely to respond to a question for which an answer has not yet been chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I would love to say that I understood it all but unfortunately not on this pass. I spent some time playing with your code earlier so I did get somewhat in depth and I'm much further along the path of binary enlightenment. I was actually thinking about picking up a book on assembly after reading a post about understanding memory. (Do you have any recommendations?) Unchecking your answer? No, You earned it. Besides, the only questions with 690 upvotes are like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby < blows my mind

Comment: and ...by the way the fact that you came back to update your post speaks volumes about your character. You're a man of true integrity and the world needs more people of your caliber. Thanks again and stay well.

Comment: @feed_me_code Glad you find it (somewhat) useful. I just checked Amazon and am not able to find the text that I learned intel assembly from back in the 90's. I would just check the reviews and see what resonates best with you. But that's if you want to go hardcore; you can get to a point of programming with bit operations without having to do assembly. A good place to start is just thinking in binary. Whenever you see a 2-digit number think about its binary (and hexadecimal) representations. A good programmer should know all the powers of 2 up to 65,536 by heart and estimate them beyond that.

Comment: 65536=256^2.. First guess. I must be good? You know all of those by heart? `2, 9, 16, 25, 36...` You are hardcore! I bet your co-workers generally don't appreciate the binary code though. (Haha) Anyway my focus is PaaS/SaaS and I'm gradually working towards creating my dream app which will need a web server faster than NGINX and a hunch tells me that I'm going to need to get as close to the machine as possible because making it work is not good enough..I want it to fly. That wont be for sometime but you helped me get my beak wet and hunch tells me I'm in for a love/hate relationship...

Comment: @feed_me_code Powers of 2 are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc. and 65536=2^16 as well as 256^2 since 256=2^8. These are just the binary numbers with a single bit equal to 1. Given your goals, consider learning about algorithms and Big-O notation and how to measure algorithm time and space (speed and memory) in this system. Learning optimal algorithms is probably even more important for overall speed than bit operations, but of course both are useful. Occasionally there are interesting problems/solutions/discussions posed on SO in the `algorithm` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I have not an experienced developer, or even an inexperienced one, but I will give you my thoughts anyway.

***1 How would you go about working towards a solution for this problem? (what's your process?)***

I would look to break into pieces, but surely everyone does that.  For example, here the values in the array are only used to pull out the indices of elements that are larger, so I'd see the first problem as pulling out the indices and the second problem as dealing with the indices alone.  I'd further simplify the latter by subtracting `i` from each index so that `j` and be compared  to `k` like so: `if j.abs < k.abs ...`, rather than `if (j-i).abs < (k-i).abs...`.  In choosing among different approaches, I tend to look for the one that is most easily understood ("reads best").

***2. In your opinion do find the Problem Question clear and easy to understand?***

Yes.

***3. How long should it take you to solve this problem?***

I refuse to answer on the grounds that it would surely incriminate me.

***4. Do you agree with the level of difficulty?***

It seems about right.  It would be a "beginner" problem at rubeque.com.

***5. If willing: please post your own solution, showcasing your style of solving this problem.***

Sure.

```
def nearest_larger(arr, i)
  ret = nearest_to_zero( arr.each_with_index
                            .select { |e,j| e > arr[i] }
                            .map    { |_,j| j-i        } )
  ret ? ret + i : nil
end
```

I looked at two ways of writing `nearest_to_zero()`.  The first is short, direct and clear, but inefficient, using `sort!`:

```
def nearest_to_zero(a)
  a.sort! { |j,k| (j.abs == k.abs) ? j <=> k : j.abs <=> k.abs }
  a.any? ? a.first : nil
end
```

More efficient, but not as pretty:

```
def nearest_to_zero(a)
  neg, pos = a.partition { |e| e < 0 }    
  case
  when neg.empty?
    pos.empty? ? nil : pos.first
  when pos.empty?
    neg.last
  else
    pos.last.abs < neg.last.abs ? pos.first : neg.last
  end 
end
```

For `arr = [2,5,4,8,10], i = 2`, the following steps are performed by `nearest_larger()`:

```
a   = arr.each_with_index.select { |e,j| e > arr[i] } # => [[5,1],[8,3],[10,4]] 
b   = a.map { |_,j| j-i }                             # => [-1,1,2] 
ret = nearest_to_zero(b)                              # => -1 
ret ? ret + i : nil                                   # => 1
```

In the first `nearest_to_zero()`, if two indices have equal absolute value (meaning they are equally close to `i` before the transformation), the tie goes to the index with the lower vlaue; else it is the index with the smaller absolute value.

In the second `nearest_to_zero()`:

```
neg, pos = [-1,1,2].partition {|e| e < 0} #  => [[-1],[1,2]]
```

The rest should be self-explanatory.

I had read about rspec, but had not used it before.  It was about time that it did.  My code passed.

Comment: +1 for contributing to the question. Please, I'm curious as to how long this solution took you (besides you're already behind bars, *haha* (play on words(like your avatar)). I'm glad you got to experiment with Rspec too (it is helpful for development). I appreciate your example because you chose two methods that I wouldn't of thought of using: `abs` and `partition` methods. I'm sure this problem still has more solutions. A line which I don't understand is `a.map { |_,j| j-i }` What is the underscore here? Thanks for contributing Cary.

Comment: @Feed, it took me 12 minutes, 13 seconds to write the code and other 6 minutes and 23 seconds to install, figure out and run rspec. The black eye resulted from an attempt to open a [Murphy bed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy_bed) I was building. I had forgotten to first secure its frame to the wall. A friend supplied the bars and hands. `a` is an array of 2-tuples, so in the block its elements could be represented by a single variable (`|e|`) or disambiguated into two (`|v,j|`).  In the latter case, if any of the variables are not needed, they can be replaced by underscores.