# How to make a logical implication condition?

Tags: ruby

I need create a conditional with a  logical implication. I have four cases:

```
  if(true and true)
    #enter
  end

  if(true and false)
    #don't enter
  end

  if(false and true)
    #enter
  end

  if(false and false)
    #enter
  end
```

How I can make this?

Comment: Please you can follow this link

[How can I write a switch statement in Ruby?][1]

Best of luck!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `a → b` is the same as `not a or b`.

Is that what you want?