# FizzBuzz doesn't fizz or buzz using case/when

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to understand how to use a conditional expression in a [Ruby case/when statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/948135/1068283). This code seems like it should work, but it only prints 1 through 100 inclusive, and never prints "Fizz", "Buzz" or "FizzBuzz".

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

(1..100).each do |n|
  case n
  when n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0
    puts "FizzBuzz"
  when n % 3 == 0
    puts "Fizz"
  when n % 5 == 0
    puts "Buzz"
  else
    puts n
  end
end
```

I'm fairly sure I'm missing something obvious and stupid, but the [documentation seems to indicate](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) that this should work. Its very similar example was:

```
a = 2

case
when a == 1, a == 2
  puts "a is one or two"
when a == 3
  puts "a is three"
else
  puts "I don't know what a is"
end
```

My Ruby version is:

```
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x86_64-linux]
```

And for completeness, the output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Comment: That'll teach me to skim rather than stop and read carefully.

Comment: Still not sure why you were downvoted, I thought your question was very well asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to put arbitrary conditions in the `when`, then you need to leave the expression off the `case`:

```
(1..100).each do |n|
  case
  when n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0
    puts "FizzBuzz"
  when n % 3 == 0
    puts "Fizz"
  when n % 5 == 0
    puts "Buzz"
  else
    puts n
  end
end
```

When you do `case n` ... `when`*boolean*, that will only trigger when `n` itself is equal to the boolean result - that is, `true` or `false`, not a number.  When you do `case`...`when` without the `n`, that's what will cause a true `when` to be triggered.

Comment: Yep, this was it. I did manage to figure it out, but by that point people had already answered and it was too late to hide my stupidity.

Comment: I think you'll find that you learn a lot faster if you stop being concerned about hiding your "stupidity" -  which is really just easily-cured ignorance, anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know. That was meant to be humorous. Obviously I need to work on that, too.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because you have `case n`, instead of just `case`. If you take that out, it'll work.

```
(1..100).each do |n|
  case
  when n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0
    puts "FizzBuzz"
  when n % 3 == 0
    puts "Fizz"
  when n % 5 == 0
    puts "Buzz"
  else
    puts n
  end
end
```

Putting a variable after `case` causes it to check against the conditions you put in `when`. The link you provided actually deals with this specific situation, the line before the code you posted specifically says this:

> The other way to use a case expression is like an if-elsif expression