# Require ruby assistance with input_user

Tags: ruby

I decided I would make a simple unwinnable "rock, paper, scissors" program and it is almost complete, however there is a issue.

I want the `user_input` to only respond when called upon, however it activates regardless of if "rock" was input, meaning, instead of typing "rock" and the program responding with "Computer played paper, you lose!" it responds with "played paper, you lose!"

```
 played scissors, you lose!
 played rock, you lose!

if #{user_input = rock}
  puts "Computer played Paper, You Lose!"
```

This is the full code:

```
print "Rock, Paper or Scissors?\n"
user_input = gets.chomp
puts "You played #{user_input}!"
if #{user_input = rock}
  puts "Computer played Paper, You Lose!"
end

if #{user_input = paper}
  puts "Computer played scissors, You Lose!"   #code
end

if #{user_input = scissors}
  puts "Computer played rock, You Lose!"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `==` when you compare, and you should be comparing the input with a string.  Also your logic could be expressed using `elsif` as there is no need to test the input three times as it can only match one (or no) value:

```
if user_input == "rock"
    puts "Computer played Paper, You Lose!"
elsif user_input == "paper"
    puts "Computer played scissors, You Lose!"
elsif user_input == "scissors"
    puts "Computer played rock, You Lose!"
else
    puts "Invalid input"
end
```

If you want case-insensitive comparison you can use `casecmp` instead like this:

```
if user_input.casecmp("rock")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a conditional-free version (doesn't handle incorrect input, though)

```
winning_moves = {
  'rock' => 'paper',
  'scissors' => 'rock',
  'paper' => 'scissors',
}

puts "Computer played #{winning_moves[user_input]}, You Lose!"
```

Comment: I like this, much more Rubyesque

Answer (score 1):

The equality in Ruby is `==` or `.eql`.

`=` is assignment.

Please replace the `=` with `==` in your `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

Or consider a `case` statement. See "[How to write a switch statement in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/)"

```
case user_input
when "rock"
  puts "Computer played Paper, You Lose!"
when "paper"
  puts "Computer played scissors, You Lose!"
when "scissors"
  puts "Computer played rock, You Lose!"
else
  puts "Invalid input"
end
```

Or more DRYly:

```
computer_plays = case user_input
                   when "rock"
                     "paper"
                  when "paper"
                     "scissors"
                  when "scissors"
                     "rock"
                  end
puts "Computer played #{computer_plays}, You Lose!" if computer_plays
```

Comment: True - given the OP's experience level I just wanted to introduce a different concept - forgot to past the link I was going to though