# Why is `return a or b` a void value expression error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, return, operator-precedence, or-operator

This is just fine:

```
def foo
  a or b
end
```

This is also fine:

```
def foo
  return a || b
end
```

This returns `void value expression`:

```
def foo
  return a or b
end
```

Why? It doesn't even get executed; it fails the syntax check. What does `void value expression` mean?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have removed all reference to the `||` operator and the question still stands. Please re-open.

Comment: @MsYvette I'm sorry, I should've taken that into account. However, I hope that it can still show that the question this is marked as a duplicate of does not answer my question.

Comment: @muistooshort Why did you mark this as duplicate? I saw that question and it did not answer my question, but sawa's answer did.

Comment: I saw it as yet another precedence issue (which it is) but perhaps I was too harsh so I'll reopen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`return a or b` is interpreted as `(return a) or b`, and so the value of `return a` is necessary to calculate the value of `(return a) or b`, but since `return` never leaves a value in place (because it escapes from that position), it is not designed to return a valid value in the original position. And hence the whole expression is left with `(some_void_value) or b`, and is stuck. That is what it means.

Answer (score 6):

In "[Does `return` have precedence to certain operators in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800242)" which I asked, [*Stefan*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800242/does-return-have-precedence-to-certain-operators-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment86615568_49800242) explained in a comment that the `or` and `and` are actually **control flow operators** and should not be used as *boolean* operators (`||` and `&&` respectively).

He also referenced "[Using “and” and “or” in Ruby](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)":

> `and` and `or` originate (like so much of Ruby) in Perl. In Perl, they were largely used to modify control flow, similar to the `if` and `unless` statement modifiers. (...)

They provide the following examples:

### `and`

> ```
> foo = 42 && foo / 2
> ```
>
> This will be equivalent to:
>
> ```
> foo = (42 && foo) / 2 # => NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass
> ```

The goal is to assign a number to `foo` and reassign it with half of its value. Thus the `and` operator is useful here due to its low precedence, it modifies/**controls** what would be the normal **flow** of the individual expressions:

> ```
> foo = 42 and foo / 2 # => 21
> ```

It can also be used as a reverse `if` statement in a loop:

> ```
> next if widget = widgets.pop
> ```

Which is equivalent to:

> ```
> widget = widgets.pop and next
> ```

### `or`

> useful for chaining expressions together

If the first expression fails, execute the second one and so on:

> ```
> foo = get_foo() or raise "Could not find foo!"
> ```

It can also be used as a:

> reversed `unless` statement modifier:
>
> ```
> raise "Not ready!" unless ready_to_rock?
> ```

Which is equivalent to:

> ```
> ready_to_rock? or raise "Not ready!"
> ```

Therefore as [sawa explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935294/6225838) the `a or b` expression in:

> ```
> return a or b
> ```

Has lower precedence than `return a` which, when executed, escapes the current context and does not provide any value (*void value*). This then triggers the error ([repl.it execution](https://repl.it/repls/SeashellDapperDevelopments)):

> (repl):1: void value expression
>
> ```
> puts return a or b
>               ^~
> ```

This answer was made possible due to [*Stefan* comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800242/does-return-have-precedence-to-certain-operators-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment86615568_49800242).

Answer (score 2):

Simply because `or` has [lower precedence](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4) than `||` which means `return a` will be executed before `or b`, `or b` is therefore unreachable