# Chef - print log at the end of statement if source isn't valid

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

this is my code:

```
if node['app']['source']
    src = "#{node['app']['source']}\\#{node['app']['file_name']}"
else 
    src = "second_source"
end
```

I want to add a log.warn at the end of my statement in case of any source isn't valid,
something like:

```
if node['app']['source']
    src = "#{node['app']['source']}\\#{node['app']['file_name']}"
else 
    src = "second_source"
whatever
    Chef::Log.warn "This path #{src} is not supported, check attributes again"
    return
end
```

I will glad if somebody has an any idea,
Thank you...

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/948157/1184717)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't how code works, a condition can either be true or false, and the two branches of `if`/`else` cover both cases. You would have to come up with a way to check if a source is valid and use `if`/`elsif`/`else` or similar.