# Generating Page Headings by Path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to auto generate page headings by path and currently I have this in my application_helper. The method works but is there a simpler way to write this?

```
def page_headings
  if current_page? about_path
    "about"
  elsif
    current_page? members_path
      "members"
  elsif
    current_page? sponsors_path
      "sponsors"
  elsif
    current_page? events_path
      "events"
  elsif
    current_page? membership_path
      "join us"
  elsif
    current_page? womens_path
      "women's page"
  elsif
    current_page? new_session_path
      "log in"
  elsif
    current_page? new_user_path
      "register"
  end
end
```

Then, in my partial, I add this:

```
<%= page_headings.upcase %>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the page title using an HTML title tag? Or are you simply rendering this text to the page? Also, are these actions all part of the same controller?

Comment: Looks like a classic [switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-to-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby)

Comment: @DavePowers I'm trying to utilize DRY in my HTML code so I want to render the text to the page. All the actions are in different controllers, that's why I put my method in application_helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more compact way would be with a case statement:

```
def current_path
  request.env['PATH_INFO']
end

def page_headings
  case current_path
  when about_path then "about"
  when members_path then "members"
  when sponsors_path then "sponsors"
  when events_path then "events"
  when membership_path then "join us"
  when womens_path then "women's page"
  when new_session_path then "log in"
  when new_user_path then "register"
  else
    puts "PAGE TITLE MISSING" if Rails.env.development?
    "My App Name"
  end
end
```

However a common pattern for this in Rails is to consider the title as part of the view layer, and use `provide` and `yield` from your views like this:

```
# app/layouts/application.html.erb
<title><%= yield(:title) + ' | ' if content_for?(:title) %>My App</title>

# app/views/about/index.html.erb
<% provide(:title, "About") %>
<h1>About</h1>

# app/views/sponsors/index.html.erb
<% provide(:title, "Sponsored by #{@sponsor.name}") %>
<h1>Sponsored by <%= @sponsor.name %></h1>
```

The upside of the case statement is it's easy to keep everything all in one place, but the downside is that it's far away from where you actually define what a page looks like, and could potentially use content from instance variables in the title.

Comment: This won't work as written. The [`current_page?` method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3f) is missing a required argument.

Comment: @DavePowers Thanks for spotting that. I've made an edit to use `current_path` instead. Funny how both answers missed the same thing.

Comment: @Unixmonkey I keep getting an `undefined local variable or method 'current_path'` error using `case current_path`. Tried a couple different combos and nothing's worked so far.

Comment: @CarolineNguyen Sorry, I forgot that `current_path` isn't built-in to Rails. I've edited the answer with a simple implementation that should work for you.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!