# Ruby switch outputting unexpected value

Tags: ruby

I don't work in Ruby day-to-day, but I'm attempting to brush up on it. On exercism.io, there's an exercise I'm attempting to complete and the solution I came up with isn't working. Here's the test code:

```
class ResistorColorDuoTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_brown_and_black
    # skip
    assert_equal 10, ResistorColorDuo.value(["brown", "black"])
  end
end
```

This is the solution I came up with:

```
module ResistorColorDuo
    def self.value(colors)
        case colors
        when (colors - ["brown", "black"]).empty?
            10
        else
            -1
        end
    end
end
```

The output from the method is -1. I can't figure out what I've fouled up. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Tip: For simple arrays of single words use `%w[ brown black ]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `case` like it was an `if`.

```
(colors - ["brown", "black"]).empty?
```

evalutes to `true` so `true` is compared to your `colors`

switch to if-else

```
def self.value(colors)
  if (colors - ["brown", "black"]).empty?
    10
  else
    -1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to be throwing more stuff at it, but that gets the job done. Thank you so much for your prompt reply. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure Sir

Answer (score 2):

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269911/14454939

```
colors = ["brown", "black"]

case
when (colors - ["brown", "black"]).empty?
    10
else
    -1
end
# => 10

colors = ["brown", "blue"]

case
when (colors - ["brown", "black"]).empty?
    10
else
    -1
end
# => -1
```

Edit: I didn't really think of it until now, but is there a reason you can't do?:

```
colors = ["brown", "blue"]

case colors
when ["brown", "black"]
    10
when ["brown", "blue"]
    20
else
    -1
end
# => 20
```

or if order shouldn't matter:

```
colors = ["brown", "blue"]

case colors.sort
when ["black", "brown"] #.sort if you don't want to sort manually
    10
when ["blue", "brown"]
    20
else
    -1
end
# => 20
```

Comment: Correct, but using `case` like this offers very little advantage over a more conventional `if` / `else` chain.

Comment: @tadman True. I've added a couple of more case-y things in case they help.