# Case statement - Ruby

Tags: ruby, case

I'm writing a simple method which counts how much I need to pay for renting a car.
However when I execute it, it always return else statement "nothing" . What is wrong here ?

```
def rental_car_cost(d)
    case d 
      when  d < 3 
        puts d * 40 
      when  d >=3  &&  d < 7 
        puts d * 40 - 20 
      when  d >= 7 
        puts d * 40 - 50
      else
        puts "nothing"
    end
end

rental_car_cost(5)

nothing
```

Comment: In such a scenario you're probably better of using an [if-statement](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression) with `elsif` conditions.

Comment: thank you for your response, I will look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case d` expects single values in `when`, not conditions.

```
def rental_car_cost(d)
  case
  when d < 3
    puts d * 40
  when  d >=3  &&  d < 7
    puts d * 40 - 20
  when  d >= 7
    puts d * 40 - 50
  else
    puts "nothing"
  end
end
```

If you want to use `case d` then you should have something like this:

```
def rental_car_cost(d)
  case d
  when 3
    puts d * 40
  when 7
    puts d * 40 - 20
  else
    puts "nothing"
  end
end
```

Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-to-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby?rq=1) for more examples.

Comment: For you second code block you probably want to use ranges. `when -Float::INFINITY...3`, `when 3...7`, and an `else`.

Comment: good point here @3limin4tor I'm not familiar with this syntax yet but I'll have a look at it.

Comment: here is an example https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/065f5c249b78621cbb2726f81753ac6a

Comment: oh nice ! Thank you again.